# Problem in the derivation of the Landé $g$-factor

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, atomic-physics, quantum-spin, perturbation-theory

I was watching a lecture on Youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NSac7cMQnJw&t=971s) where the professor derives the Landé $g$-factor for the weak-field Zeeman effect. As part of the derivation he writes the equation (time stamp 4:10)
$$
\alpha^{-1}[J^2,[J^2 , \mathbf S]] = (\mathbf S\cdot \mathbf J) \mathbf J - \frac12 (J^2 \mathbf S + \mathbf S J^2) \tag{*}
$$
for some constant $\alpha$. I tried this derivation myself, but ran into some hiccups which made me question the validity of this equation. Starting with just a single component of the inner commutator on the left,
$$
\begin{align*}
[J^2 , S_x] &= [L^2+S^2 + 2\mathbf L \cdot \mathbf S, S_x] = 2[\mathbf L \cdot \mathbf S, S_x]\\&= 2 [L_xS_x + L_yS_y + L_zS_z, S_x] \\&= 2(L_y S_y S_x -L_y S_xS_y + L_z S_z S_x - L_z S_x S_z) \\ &= 2(-L_y[S_x, S_y] + L_z[S_z,S_x]) \\ &= 2i\hbar(S_yL_z - S_z L_y) = 2i\hbar (\mathbf S \times \mathbf L)_x
\end{align*}
$$
(using the fact that all components of $ \mathbf L$ commute with all components of $\mathbf S$ to bunch the $S$'s together). I generalized this to
$$
[J^2 , \mathbf S] = 2i\hbar (\mathbf S \times \mathbf L) = 2i\hbar (\mathbf S \times (\mathbf J - \mathbf S)) = 2i\hbar (\mathbf S \times \mathbf J).
$$
Moving on to a single component of the whole commutator on the left, we have
$$
\begin{align*}
[J^2,[J^2 , S_x]] &= 2i\hbar [J^2, (\mathbf S \times \mathbf J)_x] \\ &=2i\hbar[J^2, S_yJ_z - S_z J_y] \\ &= 2i\hbar \{ [J^2, S_y J_z ] - [J^2, S_z J_y]\}.
\end{align*}
$$
But
$$
[A,BC] = ABC - BCA = ABC - BAC + BAC - BCA = [A,B]C + B[A,C],
$$
so
$$
\begin{align*}
[J^2,[J^2 , S_x]] &= 2i\hbar \{ [J^2, S_y]J_z  + [J^2, J_z]S_y - [J^2, S_z]J_y  - [J^2, J_y]S_z\} \\ &= 2i\hbar\{ [J^2, S_y]J_z - [J^2, S_z]J_y  \} \\ &= 2i\hbar \{2i\hbar (\mathbf S \times \mathbf J)_y J_z - 2i\hbar (\mathbf S \times \mathbf J)_z J_y \} \\ &= -4\hbar^2 \{ (\mathbf S \times \mathbf J) \times \mathbf J\}_x.
\end{align*}
$$
Once again, I generalized and used the BAC-CAB rule for triple cross products to obtain
$$
\begin{align*}
[J^2,[J^2 , \mathbf S]] &= -4\hbar^2[ (\mathbf S \times \mathbf J) \times \mathbf J] \\ &=-4\hbar^2[-(\mathbf J \cdot \mathbf J)\mathbf S + (\mathbf S\cdot \mathbf J)\mathbf J]\\ &=-4\hbar^2[(\mathbf S\cdot \mathbf J)\mathbf J - J^2\mathbf S],
\end{align*}
$$
which concludes the LHS. On the other hand, the RHS seems to be
$$ 
\begin{align*}
(\mathbf S\cdot \mathbf J) \mathbf J - \frac12 (J^2 \mathbf S + \mathbf S J^2) &= (\mathbf S\cdot \mathbf J) \mathbf J - \frac12 ( J^2\mathbf S  + J^2\mathbf S - [J^2, \mathbf S]) \\ &= (\mathbf S\cdot \mathbf J) \mathbf J -   J^2\mathbf S  + i\hbar(\mathbf S \times \mathbf J).
\end{align*}
$$
This is so tantalizingly close to the required result, yet I can't seem to get rid of the extra $i\hbar(\mathbf S \times \mathbf J)$ term. At the same time, I am inclined to trust the MIT professor more than myself, so what went wrong with this derivation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems with your derivation. The first one is in the calculation of $[\vec S,\vec J^2]$. In the final step, you are implicitly using $\vec S\times \vec S$ which is false. A close attention to the anticommutation rules gives:
$$
\vec S\times\vec S = i\hbar\vec S
$$
so this leads to:
$$
[\vec J{}^2,\vec S] = 2i\hbar((\vec S\times \vec J)-i\hbar \vec S)
$$

You also have a second problem in the triple cross product formula. If you look closely, you are implicitly assuming that the three operators commute when you apply it.

Instead, you'd get:
$$
((\vec S\times \vec J)\times \vec J)_k = S_lJ_kJ_l-S_kJ_lJ_l\\
= S_lJ_lJ_k+S_l i\hbar\epsilon_{klm}J_m-S_kJ_lJ_l
$$
so in vectorial notation:
$$
(\vec S\times \vec J)\times \vec J = (\vec S\cdot \vec J)\vec J+i\hbar(\vec S\times \vec J)-\vec S\vec J{}^2
$$
as you can see, you forgot the extra cross product term and the ordering of your second term was a bit cavalier. You can further symmetrize the third, final term:
$$
\vec S\vec J{}^2 = \frac{1}{2}(\vec S\vec J{}^2+\vec J{}^2\vec S-[\vec J{}^2,\vec S])\\
=\frac{1}{2}(\vec S\vec J{}^2+\vec J{}^2\vec S)-\frac{1}{2} [\vec J{}^2,\vec S]
$$
to get:
$$
(\vec S\times \vec J)\times \vec J = (\vec S\cdot \vec J)\vec J+i\hbar(\vec S\times \vec J)-\frac{1}{2}(\vec S\vec J{}^2+\vec J{}^2\vec S)+\frac{1}{2} [\vec J{}^2,\vec S]
$$

Incorporating these modifications, you'd rather get:
$$
[\vec J{}^2,[\vec J{}^2,\vec S]] = 2i\hbar[\vec J{}^2,(\vec S\times \vec J)-i\hbar \vec S)]\\
= 2i\hbar([\vec J{}^2,\vec S]\times \vec J+\vec S\times[\vec J{}^2,\vec J]-i\hbar[\vec J{}^2,\vec S])\\
= -4\hbar^2(((\vec S\times \vec J)-i\hbar \vec S)\times \vec J-\frac{1}{2}[\vec J{}^2,\vec S])\\
= -4\hbar^2((\vec S\cdot \vec J)\vec J+i\hbar(\vec S\times \vec J)-\frac{1}{2}(\vec S\vec J{}^2+\vec J{}^2\vec S)+\frac{1}{2} [\vec J{}^2,\vec S]-i\hbar(\vec S\times \vec J)-\frac{1}{2}[\vec J{}^2,\vec S])\\
= -4\hbar^2((\vec S\cdot \vec J)\vec J-\frac{1}{2}(\vec S\vec J{}^2+\vec J{}^2\vec S))
$$
which is the advertised form, with $\alpha = -4\hbar^2$ (which has the correct dimensions).

Hope this helps and tell me if something's not clear.

Comment: Yup, this was clear, thanks so much!

Comment: sorry there is still a mistake I'll rectify it (it's tricky to get everything right)

Comment: Again, thanks for the answer. Those identities I falsely used just seemed so apparent from when I studied electrodynamics, which is why I guess operators are so difficult to work with...